# Prohibit unknown values?

Tags: python, colander

Can I raise an error with colander, if values are in the payload that are not in the schema? Thus, allowing only whitelisted fields?

This is a sample:

```
# coding=utf-8
from colander import MappingSchema, String, Length
from colander import SchemaNode


class SamplePayload(MappingSchema):
    name = SchemaNode(String())
    foo  = SchemaNode(Int())


class Sample(MappingSchema):
    type = SchemaNode(String(), validator=Length(max=32))
    payload = SamplePayload()

# This json should not be accepted (and should yield something like: Unknown field in payload: bar

{  
   "type":"foo",
   "payload":{  
      "name":"a name",
      "foo":123,
      "bar":false
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about Colander but the API contains [validators](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#validators). Does any of these do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [the docs of `colander.Mapping`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#colander.Mapping)

Creating a mapping with `colander.Mapping(unknown='raise')`  will cause a `colander.Invalid` exception to be raised when unknown keys are present in the cstruct during deserialization.

According to [issue 116 in the tracker](https://github.com/Pylons/colander/issues/116), the way to apply this to a Schema object is to override the `schema_type` method:

```
class StrictMappingSchema(MappingSchema):
    def schema_type(self, **kw):
        return colander.Mapping(unknown='raise')

class SamplePayload(StrictMappingSchema):
    name = SchemaNode(String())
    foo  = SchemaNode(Int())
```

Comment: This is only referencing to the Mapping Type, right? I want that for the entire schema.

Comment: @shredding Perhaps you could add a schema and an example of data that should be rejected to the question.

Comment: Thank you! I added an example!